# how to get matched utterance inside lambda used with amazon lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

i have created a bot in amazon lex and an utterance like

> "show me top ten vendors"

so if i type

> "show me top ten vendrs"

lex still matches it with utterance even though it has a spelling mistake which is ok for me. but i need to know what utterance was matched with my input transcript inside lambda. is it possible to do?
i tried to find it inside event object which is passed to lambda but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the matched intent in the event object sent from Lex to Lambda as `event.currentIntent.name`.  The full event format is documented here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html
The utterance can be referenced as `event.inputTranscript`

The following example collects the currentIntent and utterance and writes both to the log file as expected.  Hope this helps!

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
console.log("incoming event details: " + JSON.stringify(event));
console.log("Matched intent: " + event.currentIntent.name);
console.log("Utterance: " + event.inputTranscript);


};
```

Comment: There can be multiple utterances in intent. How can I determine which utterance was matched?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to identify utterance as well.

Comment: its wrong answer, the `inputTranscript` will only tell what the user has typed not the utterance it matched.

Comment: @sid8491 - the original question was asking how to identify the typed "utterance"

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it is not possible for Lex to tell which utterance it matched to determine the intent.

You can however do one thing, after intent is matched write a code to get the utterances of matched intent, then match every input to each of those utterances and select the closest one.

```
client_model = boto3.client('lex-models')
bot_details = client_model.get_intent(
    name='name_of_your_intent',
    versionOrAlias='$LATEST'
    )
```

`bot_details['sampleUtterances']` will contain all the utterances. You can use some string matching library like [FuzzyWuzzy](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) for matching closest string.

Hope it helps.